# Springboot 3.x migration - cannot access HttpClient Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am migrating one of our application from `springboot` `2.7.x` to `3.1.x` and getting the below error while compiling the app

```
error: cannot access HttpClient
return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpclient);
       ^
class file for org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient not found
```

The class is `A.java`

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.ClosableHttpClient;


@Configuration
public class A {

// other code blocks

@Bean
@DependsOn({"httpclient"})
public ClientHttpRequestFactory reqFactory(ClosableHttpClient httpClient){ 
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);  ===> The error line
}
```

IntelliJ shown the error as RequiredType HttpClient, Provided ClosableHttpClient

`build.gradle` has only one library related to httpclient as below

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14
```

Please let me know what is the equivalent library that supports for spring boot 3 and the corresponding package details to import

Also, I would like to know does it require rewriting the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support to HttpClient 4 has been [removed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.1-Release-Notes#dependency-management-for-apache-httpclient-4) in SpringBoot 3.1.

You need to migrate to HttpClient 5.

> Dependency Management for Apache HttpClient 4
>
> Support for Apache HttpClient 4 with RestTemplate was removed in Spring Framework 6, in favor of Apache HttpClient 5. Spring Boot 3.0 includes dependency management for both HttpClient 4 and 5. Applications that continue to use HttpClient 4 can experience errors when using RestTemplate that are difficult to diagnose.
>
> **Spring Boot 3.1 removes dependency management for HttpClient 4 to encourage users to move to HttpClient 5 instead**.